# Simple LINQ statement failing - why?

Tags: asp.net, listviewitem

I have the following 2 lines;

```
var currentPage = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mydir", "*.pdf")
  .Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

var allItems = currentPage.OrderBy(c => c)
  .Select(c => new ListViewItem(c)).ToArray();
```

The above 2 line is failing with "CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem.ListViewItem(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType)' has some invalid arguments". The error is, according to VS2010, from "new ListViewItem(**c**)".

I am thinking I am missing something really obivous - but I just cannot see it.

Comment: Is this WPF, Winforms or Web Forms?

Comment: Sorry - it is System.Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you're trying to set bind the ListView to this array of specified file names. Have you tried setting the DataSource of the ListView?

Like this:

```
myListView.DataSource = null;

var currentPage = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mydir", "*.pdf")
  .Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

var dataArray = currentPage.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();

myListView.DataSource = dataArray;
myListView.DataBind();
```

More on binding to an IEnumerable : http://forums.asp.net/t/1319474.aspx/1

Hope that helps...

Comment: Ofcourse - the Datasource. Some times the answer is right there in front of me :) Thx!

Answer (score 2):

`Directory.GetFiles()` returns an array of strings. You are then taking those strings and trying to create an array of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem` by passing in a string into the ListViewItem constructor.

The problem is there is no constructor of `ListViewItem` that takes in a string.

The [only constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.listviewitem.aspx) takes in a ListViewItemType

```
public ListViewItem(
    ListViewItemType itemType
)
```

This is why you got the error

> The best overloaded method match for System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem.ListViewItem(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType) has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yeah okay - that makes sence. But what would then be the right approach forward - getting my linq statement/output into a listview?

Comment: You should look at binding section in the [MSDN article: ListView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx#BindingDataToTheListViewControl) The easiest way would be `ListView.Datasource = currentPage;`

Comment: Not sure if this will work, 
            var allItems = currentPage.OrderBy(c => c).Select(c => new ListViewItem(ListViewItemType.DataItem){DataItem=c}).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If this is [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) you should Remove the `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` directive and ensure you have `using System.Windows.Forms;` instead.</strike>

If this is [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) you can't create an instance of `ListViewItem` with a `String` as the parameter for the constructor. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298780.aspx) on MSDN for more info on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx) a result from the previous query that is a string(of the filename). The [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.listviewitem.aspx) does not have a constructor that accepts that.

Try reading the strings in a List or something and then add it as a datasource to the ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

var allItems = currentPage.OrderBy(c => c).Select(c => new ListViewItem((ListViewItemType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ListViewItemType), c, true))).ToArray();

Gets rid of the error, dont know if that will help you